# Select element options not opening on first click with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I have a html template with four selects. The same thing happens to me in all four. When I click on the select the first time it doesn't open, but after that, the following times it does. I want the options to be open the first time too. The selects are like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
 

 <div class="input-group">
                <select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" id="src" name="src">
                    {% for value, label in jobs%}
                    <option value="{{ value }}">{{ label }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
                </select>
    
            </div>
```

The javaScript part is this. I have tried to do it in many ways but I can't.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Wait for the DOM to be ready
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
          
        // Select all <select> elements
        var selectElements = document.querySelectorAll("select");
    
        // Apply the Bootstrap Select plugin to each <select> element
        selectElements.forEach(function(selectElement) {
            console.log("DOM ready");
            new bootstrap.Select(selectElement);


        });
    });

    </script>
```

and this is the view:

```
def jos(request):
    context = {
        'jobs': get_values()
    }

    return render(request, 'myHtml.html', context)
```

```js
 

   // Wait for the DOM to be ready
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

      // Select all <select> elements
      var selectElements = document.querySelectorAll("select");

      // Apply the Bootstrap Select plugin to each <select> element
      selectElements.forEach(function(selectElement) {
        new bootstrap.Select(selectElement);
      });
    });
```

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}
{% for group in user.groups.all %}
    {% if group.customgroup.access_level == 1 or group.customgroup.access_level == 2 %}
    <br>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />

<div class="input-group">
  <select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" id="src1" name="src">
    <option value="value">Label</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" id="src2" name="src">
    <option value="value">Label</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" id="src3" name="src">
    <option value="value">Label</option>
  </select>
</div>


    <a href="{% url 'main_page' %}" class="btn btn-dark text-white">{% trans 'mainPage' %}</a>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    {% else %}
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10">
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                    <h4 class="alert-heading">{% trans 'noAccess' %}</h4>
                    <p>{% trans 'mensajeErrorAccess' %}</p> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Add your views to the question please.

Comment: The demo I created above seems to work fine (aside from the console error). Questions about Bootstrap should show rendered HTML, not app code. Please update the demo to accurately show your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You missed to include bootstrap stylesheet so you should include the below css library:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: No, I have tried and it still opens on the second try and with that stylesheet the options won't show

Comment: might be some other libraries are conflicting. could you confirm if you have more js or css libraries included on the same page?